# The mule, the donkey and the zebra

Tags: logical-deduction

Let's have thirteen stalls, equidistantly spaced. In each stall is a trough which contains four liters of water. In the first stall is a mule, in the second is a donkey and in the eleventh is a zebra. When an animal takes a drink, it must drink all four liters. From stall to stall the animals require two-thirds of a liter of water. The donkey and the zebra, but not the mule, must burn the water they drank before taking another drink. The mule must move from the first stall to the thirteenth stall and then return to the first. The donkey must travel from the second to the thirteenth stall, and then go back to the first stall. The zebra has to go from the eleventh stall to the first, before proceeding to the thirteenth stall. After the three animals have completed their travels, which trough remains untouched?

Comment: Are there any more restrictions on how much water the mule can take? I can see four possible answers at the moment.

Comment: I think there must be more to it?  The mule drinks every time it can, and goes from 1 -> 13 -> 12 ... -> 2 -> 1.   So regardless of what the donkey and zebra do, the mule will end up drinking all the water?

Comment: Can two animals be in the same stall at the same time? Also, is it a typo that the mule and the donkey are both supposed to end up in the first stall?

Comment: I agree with @hexomino. After the zebra and donkey requirements have been met, there are five stalls with water remaining. After drinking from 1, the mule can stop at any three of the remaining four to consume enough water for its round trip.

Comment: @hexomino. No restrictions.

Comment: @ColinM. All three animals are making the round trip and they consume two-thirds of a liter of water from stall to stall. The puzzle is to figure out from which stalls each animal drinks water.

Comment: @Rob Watts. The mule and the donkey both end up in the first stall. During the trips, when one animal drinks from a trough, then that trough remains empty.

Comment: @fljx. When you name the stalls from which each animal drinks water, you will find the untouched trough.

Answer (score 2):

The paths of the three animals can be considered independently so moving the

Donkey first:

> Donkey drinks at 2, moves to 8 and drinks there, moves to 13 and then one step back to 12 and drinks there, moves to 6 and drinks there, moves to 1. As it it doesn't need to move any further it doesn't drink from 1. So the troughs at stalls 2, 6, 8, and 12 are now empty.

and the Zebra second:

> Zebra drinks at 11, moves to 5 and drinks there, moves to 1 and then forwards to 3 and drinks there, moves to 9 and drinks there, moves to 11. Can't drink from there but doesn't need to as it has also reached its destination. So now troughs at stalls 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, and 12 are empty, leaving troughs 1, 4, 7, 10, and 13 full for the mule.

and the Mule third:

> As the mule is not required to 'burn' all the water before drinking, it can make a number of choices. For example, it can drink at each stall as soon as it reaches it. So could drink at 1, 4, 7, 10, and 13 (at which point it will still have 12 liters of water in its belly, more than enough for the return trip. Or it can drink at 1,4,7,10 and skip drinking at 13, or drink at 1,4,7,13; or 1,4,10,13; or 1,7,10,13; and decide whether to drink at or skip drinking at 10, 7, or 4 respectively. Or it could drink at 1,4,10,7; or 1,4,13,7; skipping 13 or 10 respectively. Or drink at 1,4,13,10; or at 1,7,13,10; and decide to drink or not drink, on the way back, 7 or 4 respectively. So it appears that the mule can choose to drain all the troughs, or can choose to leave any one except 1 empty.

Thus, it appears that there is no solution unless the mule is further constrained in some way.

Comment: The puzzle states that the zebra goes from the eleventh to the first and then from the first to the thirteenth. Taking into consideration the constraints for the zebra, then she can drink from 11, 5, 3 and 9. You can figure out the rest.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Isn't that what Penguino has been doing?

Comment: And can drink from 1 too.

Comment: The  mule moves first then the donkey and last the zebra as been stated in the question.

Comment: The order they move in doesn't affect the solution. As @Penguino has explained in detail in this answer, the problem as stated has multiple valid solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a solution to this, although I found the wording somewhat ambiguous so I may have made an invalid assumption somewhere.

Assuming the following start position:
Mule: Stall 1, no water stored
Donkey: Stall 2, no water stored
Zebra: Stall 11, no water stored
Water in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

And assuming the route each would take (without taking into account water)
Mule:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1
Donkey: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1
Zebra:  11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 13

On each tick the animals either drink or move, alternately.

> Tick 1 (drink):
>  All animals drink all water in their current stall
>  Mule: Stall 1, 12/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 2, 12/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 11, 12/3 water stored
>  Water in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 2 (move):
>  Animals move to their next stall
>  Mule: Stall 2, 10/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 3, 10/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 10, 10/3 water stored
>  Water in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 3 (drink):
>  Mule has no water to drink (Stall 2 is empty) -> no change
>  Donkey and zebra can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>
>  Tick 4 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 3, 8/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 4, 8/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 9, 8/3 water stored
>  Water in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 5 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 3, 20/3 water stored
>  Donkey and zebra can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Water in 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 6 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 4, 18/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 5, 6/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 8, 6/3 water stored
>  Water in 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 7 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 4, 30/3 water stored
>  Donkey and zebra can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Water in 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 8 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 5, 28/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 6, 4/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 7, 4/3 water stored
>  Water in 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 9 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 5, 40/3 water stored
>  Donkey and zebra can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Water in 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 10 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 6, 38/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 7, 2/3 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 6, 2/3 water stored
>  Water in 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 11 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 6, 50/3 water stored
>  Donkey and zebra can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Water in 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 12 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 7, 48/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 8, 0 water stored
>  Zebra: Stall 5, 0 water stored
>  Water in 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 13 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 7, 60/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 8, 12/3 water stored
>  Zebra: has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 14 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 8, 58/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 9, 10/3 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 15 (drink):
>  Mule has no water to drink (stall 8 is empty) -> no change
>  Donkey can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Zebra has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 16 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 9, 56/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 10, 8/3 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 9, 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 17 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 9, 68/3 water stored
>  Donkey can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Zebra has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 18 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 10, 66/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 11, 6/3 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 10, 12, 13
>
>  Tick 19 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 10, 78/3 water stored
>  Donkey can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Zebra has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 12, 13
>
>  Tick 20 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 11, 76/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 12, 4/3 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 12, 13
>
>  Tick 21 (drink):
>  Mule has no water to drink (stall 11 is empty) -> no change
>  Donkey can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Zebra has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 12, 13
>
>  Tick 22 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 12, 74/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 13, 2/3 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 12, 13
>
>  Tick 23 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 12, 86/3 water stored
>  Donkey can't drink until they are empty -> no change
>  Zebra has no water to drink (Stall 5 is empty) -> no change
>  Water in 13
>
>  Tick 24 (move):
>  Mule: Stall 13, 78/3 water stored
>  Donkey: Stall 1, 0 water stored
>  Zebra stays in stall 5, 0 water
>  Water in 13
>
>  Tick 25 (drink):
>  Mule: Stall 13, 90/3 water stored
>  Donkey and Zebra have no water to drink (Stall 5 and 1 are empty) -> no chan
>  Water in [none]

Now the mule keeps moving until it has exhausted all its water, no stall is left untouched.